# post request and url not working on google app engine django project

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, django-rest-framework, web-hosting

I am hosting my blogging app on google app engine in a standard environment. the website deploys successfully. but when I try to go to any other URL like anirudhmalik.in to anirudhmalik/blog/list/ it shows me 500 server error on the server side I am using PostgreSQL instance and the logs message only show me the error 
`projects/anirudhmalik-274008/logs/appengine.googleapis.com%2Frequest_log"`

but I couldn't get any hint from this message and none of the post requests isworking on the website and everything is working fine in a local server or my local machine 
you can check the website on anirudhmalik.in 
and you can also give suggestion is google app engine is good to host your Django project and other cheap college student type hosting service  thankyou

**main.py**

```
from annyportfolio.wsgi import application
app=application
```

**app.yaml file**

````
handlers:# This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static# directory.- - url: /static 
  static_dir: static-storage/

# This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is# required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with# the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.* 
  secure: always redirect_http_response_code: 301 
  script: auto


env_variables: 
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: annyportfolio.settings ```



I am coonecting to database by using the below code
````

```
if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
    # Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
    # the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST':'<instance address>',
        'NAME': '<server name >',
        'USER': '<server user>',
        'PASSWORD': '<password of user>',

    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share how you are configuring your database in your code?

Comment: i have edit the question you can have a look at that thankyou

Answer (score 1):

I can see in your code some issues, you need to put the name of the schema (not the server name) on the property 'name' of your default dictionary and the 'host' property need to follow the Cloud SQL connection string pattern, App Engine Standard not use the public IP to reach your PostgreSQL instance

For example:

```
# Running on production App Engine, so connect to Google Cloud SQL using
# the unix socket at /cloudsql/<your-cloudsql-connection string>
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'HOST':'/cloudsql/my-project:us-central1:my-sql-instance',
        'NAME': 'mydjangoschema',
        'USER': '<server user>',
        'PASSWORD': '<password of user>',

    }
```

To create the correct host string please follow this steps

1. Run this gcloud sdk command

```
gcloud sql instances describe [YOUR_INSTANCE_NAME]
```

2. In the output, note the value shown for [CONNECTION_NAME].
3. the host string must follow this pattern `/cloudsql/[CONNECTION_NAME]` in my example is `/cloudsql/my-project:us-central1:my-sql-instance`